# How to draw a tunnel-like effect?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I know how to draw stuff in GDI but I find it difficult to determine how to draw actual shapes that are more than just squares and circles.

I'm trying to draw a tunnel, by just drawing a whole bunch of squares or rectangles overlapping each other but I can't figure out how to position then properly.

How can I draw this kind of effect?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Adding some code sample as well as screenshots of your resul|t/desired result may help.

Comment: Ok I will update my question with screenshot. Sorry I don't have code right now because I didn't know where to start (I did actually try writing some code but it was way off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Once you understand the basics of how to draw using GDI, you should be able to do things like this very easily.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Autodraw
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool canDraw;

        public class NPanel : Panel
        {
            protected override bool DoubleBuffered
            {
                get
                {
                    return base.DoubleBuffered;
                }

                set
                {
                    base.DoubleBuffered = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public NPanel nPanel = new NPanel();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            panel = nPanel;
        }

        private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (canDraw)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r <= 255; r++)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, 0, 0), 1), r, r, r, r);
                }

                for (int r = 0; r <= 255; r++)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, r, 0), 1), r, r, r, r);
                }

                for (int r = 0; r <= 255; r++)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, r), 1), r, r, r, r);
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                canDraw = false;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            canDraw = true;
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sample assumes you've a `Panel` on your `Form` that is named `panel`.

Comment: Wow thank you this is exactly what I was pictureing in my mind. How did you know I was asking for exactly this?? And do I need to provide attribution for this code?

Comment: Well, you said "overlapping rectangles", and since this used to be a pretty common effect years ago, it was the first thing that came to mind. For attribution, have a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing